# How to define method outside of an object

Tags: javascript, oop

I am quite newbie in OOP. I have lots of ajax calls and i want to combine them as an object.

Here is my function;

```
var Ajax_call = function(target) {
    this.target = target;
    this.data = function(){
        return $("#"+this.target+"").parent("form").serialize();
    };
    this.start = function(){
        status(true);
        var data = this.data();
        $.ajax({
            type : "post",
            url : $("#"+this.target+"").attr('action'),
            data : data + '&ajax=' + 1,
            dataType : "json",
            timeout : 3000,
            success : 
                function(serv){
                    if(serv.error){
                        this.denied();  ///// TypeError: undefined is not a function 
                        }
                    if(serv.done){
                        //this.succeed();
                        }
                    },
            error :
                function(x,t,m){
                    //this.failed();
                }
        });
    };

};
```

I want to define **denied()** method here;

```
$('body').on('click','#register_submit',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    Ajax_call.denied = function() {
        console.log (serv.error);
    };
    var register = new Ajax_call((this.id));
    register.start();
});
```

Thanks!

---

**HERE IS THE SOLUTION;**

I defined duplicated variable `this` to `_this`. So when js overload on it i can use `_this` instead of `this`. There is no need for prototype.

Declaration;

```
var Ajax_call = function(target) {
    this.target = target;
    this.data = function(){
        return $("#"+this.target+"").parent("form").serialize();
    };
    this.denied;
    this.start = function(){
        var _this = this; /// Js overload on this.
}
```

Ajax part;

```
    $.ajax({
        type : "post",
        url : $("#"+this.target+"").attr('action'),
        data : data + '&ajax=' + 1,
        dataType : "json",
        timeout : 3000,
        success : 
            function(serv){
                if(serv.error){
                    _this.denied(serv);  ///// Fixed
                    }
                if(serv.done){
                    //_this.succeed();
                    }
                },
        error :
            function(x,t,m){
                //_this.failed();
            }
    });
```

Usage;

```
$('body').on('click','#register_submit',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var register = new Ajax_call((this.id));
    register.denied = function(serv) {
        console.log (serv.error);
    };
    register.start();
});
```

Comment: Doesn't make sense to set the prototype method on every click. If multiple calls happen at the same time (multiple instances) the second one will overwrite the first denied method.  Maybe the following answer helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711

Comment: uhmm. i wont use this object in one page multiple times. can't it be a basic solution to set clicked button's attr disabled? or you think i must use constructor?
great article by the way.. i am trying to get it thank you.

Comment: If you don't need multiple instances then why a constructor function to create only one instance? You could declare register as an object literal: `var register = {prop1:22,prop2:function(){}}` You'll only ever have one register object and can manipulate that. I have to say that with Ajax it's better to create multiple instances as you may make multiple ajax calls at the same time. Manipulate instance specific members when needed and define shared members that won't change per instance on the prototype.

Comment: yes there might be multiple ajax call at the same time in the future. so updated the solution. if i create another object like `var lost-password = new Ajax_call();` i think there will be no problem. they will all have unique `denied` property. am i right? or any changes needed?

Comment: Correct, you can place the start function on Ajax_call.prototype.

Comment: You're welcome, hope it works out. Takes a bit of time to wrap your head around it but will give you great benefit once you do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's the scope issue for `this` as `this` has special meaning (i.e., pointing to the object the callback is called from) in callback function. Save `this` in a local variable and use it later. See the example below.

```
this.start = function(){
        var self = this;
        status(true);
        var data = this.data();
        $.ajax({
            type : "post",
            url : $("#"+this.target+"").attr('action'),
            data : data + '&ajax=' + 1,
            dataType : "json",
            timeout : 3000,
            success : 
                function(serv){
                    if(serv.error){
                        // this is replaces with self variable
                        self.denied();  ///// TypeError: undefined is not a function 
                        }
                    if(serv.done){
                        //this.succeed();
                        }
                    },
            error :
                function(x,t,m){
                    //this.failed();
                }
        });
    };
```

Comment: I have already tried that. I can define it in prototype and call it right before **register.start()** as **register.denied()** 

But i need to use it inside of **ajax_call** object so i can use "this." method in it. Thanks.

Comment: sorry, I have changed the answer.

Comment: your answer is more clear now. i also changed **self.denied(serv)** to fetch variable. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The `this` in `this.denied();` refers to that success function, not Ajax_call.  So setting the `denied` method later is working but its not getting seen properly because of how JS overloads `this`.

What you probably want is to bind `this` to that success function using something like [underscore.js's `bind()`](http://underscorejs.org/#bind).

Which would then look something like:

```
// ...
success: _.bind(function(serv){
    if(serv.error){
        this.denied();
    }
    if(serv.done){
        //this.succeed();
    }
}, this),
// ...
```

Comment: **its not getting seen properly because of how JS overloads this.**
That's the answer i was looking for. Thank you so much i can fix it without underscore.js